# Reason for CORS preflight request error

Tags: cors

If I receive this error when making a call to a third-party API service...

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

... is this something that the third-party needs to allow, as opposed to something I need to change with my request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this header needs to be included in the response from server. (Not in your request.)

[Example from mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

> To allow any resource to access your resource, you can specify:
>
> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
>
> To allow `https://developer.mozilla.org` to access your resource, you
>   can specify:
>
> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://developer.mozilla.org`